# How to remove # from in front of text in Prawn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prawn

I am using Prawn for PDF generation and have a random artifact left on the screen. I am wondering if there is a way to remove it? The code looks like this:

```
def title_page
   text_box "Title page for \##{@book.name} book", size: 30, style: :bold
end
```

When it displays on the page it shows up as "Title page for #John book" without the quote marks.

Comment: I think you want `"Title page for #{@book.name} book"`

Comment: Yes thank you. I just found the syntax had changed.

Answer (score 0):

New syntax is `Title page for #{@book.name} book`